# Using a Jetty Server with JUnit tests

Tags: java, http, junit, jetty

I've been trying to test my web app by starting a Jetty server in the BeforeClass method of my JUnit test case and then using a HttpClient to form request to the server. I get the server to start without any issues, but I keep getting 404's when I try to make  a request.

The configuration of my server is like the following:

```
  public void start() throws Exception {
        if (server == null) {
            server = new Server(PORT);
            server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

            wac = new WebAppContext();
            wac.setContextPath("/app");
            wac.setResourceBase("war");
            wac.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
            server.addHandler(wac);

            server.start();
        }
   }
```

Is there something wrong with my config? The server is running, and I can see that I am hitting it, it just can't find any resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to define this servlet as a resource in your deployment descriptor (web.xml or jetty-web.xml). Just a guess; a 404 indicates that your code isn't running at all, and therefore isn't the problem. The problem is occurring before your code even has a chance to execute.

Comment: ahaha yes, I know notice that wac.getDescriptor returns null.

Answer (score 14):

This is a complete Junit test class that uses jetty:

```
package test.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
import org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class MockPortalTest {

    private Server server;

    @Before
    public void startServer() throws Exception {
        server = new Server(8080);
        server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/app");
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");       
        webAppContext.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        server.addHandler(webAppContext);
        server.start();
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldBePreAuthenticated() throws Exception {
        String userId = "invalid";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet mockRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/app");
        mockRequest.setHeader("http-user",userId);
        HttpResponse mockResponse = client.execute(mockRequest);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(mockResponse.getEntity().getContent()));    
        // DO YOUR ASSERTIONS
    }

    @After
    public void shutdownServer() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I started with the code snippet in the first post and then started to fight my way through. The code below finally worked for me:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setContextPath("/app");
webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");       
webAppContext.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
server.addHandler(webAppContext);
server.start();

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/app/some_call");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(connection.getInputStream());
System.out.println(lines.get(0));
```

POM looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
</dependency>


<jetty.version>6.1.25</jetty.version>
```

Comment: I had to add `server.start();` after `server.addHandler(webAppContext);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set:

```
wac.setWar("/path/to/war/file");
```

Or better, use the constructor:

```
wac = new WebAppContext("/path/to/war/file", "/app");
```

Comment: I set the resource base and the class loader, so the path to the war gets set automatically. If I inspect the WebAppContext during runtime, this is at least the behavior that I see.